How can I clone a GLTF model loaded in the Autodesk Viewer?
I am trying to dynamically clone a loaded GLB model and allow the user to position it in the scene. However, when I use the model.clone() method, the model appears in the scene at the same position as the original. Any change in position affects the original model as well. Additionally, both the original and the cloned models have the same ID. Did I misunderstand the purpose of the clone() method, and should I use a different approach for this purpose? I found the SceneBuilder extension, but I don't know how to extract the geometry of the GLB model for it.
Code:
class FireExtinguisher extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {

    constructor(viewer, options){
        super(viewer, options)
        this.model = null
    }

    load(){

        const modelUrl = './GLTF/fireExtinguisher.glb'
        const loadOptions = {
            keepCurrentModels: true,
            applyRefPoint: true,
        }
        this.viewer.loadModel(modelUrl, loadOptions, this.onSuccessCallback.bind(this), this.onErrorCallback)
        return true
    }

    unload(){
        return false
    }
onSuccessCallback(model){
        
        this.model = model

        const cloned1 = model.clone()
        cloned1.id = 14

        const clonedPosition1 = { x: 10, y: 0, z: 0 };
        const clonedMatrix1 = new THREE.Matrix4();
        const clonedTranslation1 = new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(clonedPosition1.x, clonedPosition1.y, clonedPosition1.z);
        clonedMatrix1.multiply(clonedTranslation1);
        cloned1.setPlacementTransform(clonedMatrix1);

        this.viewer.impl.addModel(cloned1);
        this.viewer.impl.invalidate(true);


        const cloned2 = model.clone()

        const clonedPosition2 = { x: -10, y: 3, z: 0 };
        const clonedMatrix2 = new THREE.Matrix4()
        const clonedTranslation2 = new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(clonedPosition2.x,clonedPosition2.y,clonedPosition2.z)

        clonedMatrix2.multiply(clonedTranslation2)
        cloned2.setPlacementTransform(clonedMatrix2)

        this.viewer.impl.addModel(cloned2);
        this.viewer.impl.invalidate(true);

        const newModel = this.clone(model)
        console.log(newModel);

    }

    clone(obj){
        var clone = {};
        for(var i in obj) {
            if(typeof(obj[i])=="object" && obj[i] != null)
                clone[i] = this.clone(obj[i]);
            else
                clone[i] = obj[i];
        }
        return clone;
    }
}


I tried to break the reference between the translation matrices of the models, but without success. I also attempted to break the reference between the original and cloned model, but other errors occurred.
Thank you for your time.

According to the documentation the clone method only creates a shallow copy sharing all the inner state with the original model, so if you need multiple standalone instances in the viewer, this is probably not a good way.
Since you're working with gltf/glb data, you could load these objects using the standard three.js gltf loader (just keep in mind that the version of three.js that APS Viewer is built on top of is R71), and then add the objects into the viewer either as an overlay, or using the SceneBuilder extension.

I will use SceneBuilder, and if I understood you correctly, first I load the model using the Three.js GLTFLoader, and then dynamically use the addMesh() method as needed for each instance of the model.
Thank you very much.
